# How do I properly use asyncScheduler to know data was processed in rxjs?

Tags: rxjs

I have some basic code like this:

```js
this.events$
      .pipe(
        observeOn(asyncScheduler),
        ...
      ).subscribe(anotherObservable$);
```

This works fine in my app, but I am having a funny issue with a unit test. I put a couple of debug consoles like this:

```js
    this.events$
      .pipe()
      .subscribe(console.log.bind(null, 'sanity check inside without async'));
    this.events$
      .pipe(observeOn(asyncScheduler))
      .subscribe(console.log.bind(null, 'sanity check inside with async'));
```

If I do `from(events).subscribe(events$);` in my test, the "without async" log fires.

If I do `scheduled(events, asyncScheduler).subscribe(events$);`, nothing fires.

I can't seem to fake the input to get my pipe on the async scheduler to fire. My test just needs that pipe to fire to see that something was called.

Answer (score 0):

Realized right after posting:

```js
scheduled(events, asyncScheduler).subscribe(events$);
await lastValueFrom(events$)
```